# cant add textview to this xml code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, textview

[image]hi I get I source code for adding a selectable textview option for the text for app. now I want to edit this source code where I want to add some more text views but when I add it it gives me errors. so my question is how can I add more textviews to this following source code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#ffffff"
        >
    <com.zyz.mobile.example.ObservableScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
        <com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView
                android:id="@+id/main_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@string/text">



          <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/main_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@string/text"/>
          </com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView>
                 </com.zyz.mobile.example.ObservableScrollView>
```

**Logcat output:**

```
02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zyz.mobile.example/com.zyz.mobile.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:767)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at com.zyz.mobile.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    02-27 00:19:37.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9783):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
```

and my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SelectableTextView mTextView;
    private int mTouchX;
    private int mTouchY;
    private final static int DEFAULT_SELECTION_LEN = 5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // make sure the TextView's BufferType is Spannable, see the main.xml
        mTextView = (SelectableTextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        mTextView.setDefaultSelectionColor(Color.YELLOW);


        mTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                showSelectionCursors(mTouchX, mTouchY);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextView.hideCursor();

            }
        });
        mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mTouchX = (int) event.getX();
                mTouchY = (int) event.getY();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showSelectionCursors(int x, int y) {
        int start = mTextView.getPreciseOffset(x, y);

        if (start > -1) {
            int end = start + DEFAULT_SELECTION_LEN;
            if (end >= mTextView.getText().length()) {
                end = mTextView.getText().length() - 1;


            }
            mTextView.showSelectionControls(start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you add what exactly?

Comment: add a textview and post that code, with errors that you get

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a textview in this layout?

Comment: question is now edited...errors and java code is also added.

Comment: don't put your textView in your SelectableTextView. it is not a viewgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your SelectableTextView is not a subclass ViewGroup so you have to close the tag with `/>` at the end like:

```
   <com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView
            android:id="@+id/main_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:text="@string/text"
            />
```

and remove this part then at the bottom:

```
  </com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView>
```

because it is not a ViewGroup! you cannot contain other views inside it.

so the problem that you have is not adding another textview, it is having this special SelectableTextView incorrectly implemented in your layout that is why your app crashes

Comment: ok I added another same selectable textview..now suppose I have seven to 10 different textviews when I wanna selectable so how can I set the java code for all these selectable textviews? should I repeat the same java code for other textviews as well or I can do it in a single code?

Comment: write your View.OnLongClickListener once and attach the same listener to different textviews

Answer (score 0):

Please take a @njzk2's comment above - `SelectableTextView` is not a `ViewGroup` so it can't contain child `View`s. You'll need to remove the `TextView` from your `SelectableTextView` and call `setText()` on the `SelectableTextView` instead.

Another issue: I'm guessing `ObservableScrollView` extends Android's native `ScrollView`, right? If that's true, `ObservableScrollView` can only contain 1 direct child. In this case you need a `ViewGroup` like `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` to hold everything else. Try this (making `ObservableScrollView` the parent):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.zyz.mobile.example.ObservableScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="#ffffff">

            <com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView
                android:id="@+id/main_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@string/text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</com.zyz.mobile.example.ObservableScrollView>
```

Then add your `ObservableScrollView`s to the LinearLayout

Comment: Still giving the same error

Comment: Did you try @njzk2's solution in the comments to your question? I think he's probably right. Though my answer above would still solve an issue with your code, I believe, it is a different issue.

Comment: <com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView
                android:id="@+id/main_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@string/text">

               

            </com.zyz.mobile.example.SelectableTextView> this thing works by adding a similar view. now how to write java code for these two selectable textviews to be selectable?

Comment: What does SelectableTextView do that TextView does not? Does it subclass TextView? According to the docs: "To allow users to copy some or all of the TextView's value and paste it somewhere else, set the XML attribute android:textIsSelectable to "true" or call setTextIsSelectable(true). The textIsSelectable flag allows users to make selection gestures in the TextView, which in turn triggers the system's built-in copy/paste controls." So you can make a normal TextView's text selectable pretty easily. If that's all you want, why not use the native TextView?

Comment: yes I know that but what I want is to add a highlight option for the user in my app. so that the user hightlight the selectable text for their own. can I do that with a simple textview? I want a highlight option just like in google play book.

Comment: Well, when you select text by long pressing (or some other means) the text is automatically highlighted. My HTC Once highlights in turquoise. Is your goal to let your user highlight multiple, non-contiguous phrases or just 1 at a time?

Comment: so how I can popup an option with textisSelectable that shows colors for highlight that when user click on that that area becomes highlighted and stored in the app. so that when user restart the app that highlighted area remain highlighted?

Comment: now look at the image at the top that is what I want.

Comment: I think that's beyond the scope of this question, so you should probably open another question for that. Since I haven't seen the code for SelectableTextView, I don't know how to solve that problem, but what you're seeing in the error you originally posted I think is a result of what other commenters/ answers have indicated - SelectableTextView is not a ViewGroup.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your co-operation